# OpenAL Leak- OALSource:AddPlaybackMessage

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks, openal

I am currently using openAl in my game . I am getting the memory leak whose responsible frame is  `

> OALSource:AddPlaybackMessage

` What I am doing is that after my game finishes i delete all the buffers allocated to the Source and free other pcmdata pointers etc .. before the starting the game i re-initialize the source and their buffers with the audio data. At this stage am getting this leak. Any idea why its happening ..... Some posts say its a bug in apple's OpenAl library but i dont think so .. Apple must have done something about it ....

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same leak. I create and release a lot of sound sources and the leak happens quite randomly (maybe 1 in 10, maybe 1 in 50...) it happens more the faster I create and release. There's a post on the official apple forums as well with no responses as well...

Comment: It is my post bro... but i figured it out ..check the answer below..

Comment: I sorted out my issue. I don't understand it but it was one of my sound files... using a different sound resolved the leaking. I tried re-creating the file in question 3 times before I finally got one that didn't leak... makes no sense to me, going to chalk it up as an Apple OpenAL lib issue but it seems resolved now.

Comment: Below answer is what solved my issue but i don't find any logical point in it how it solved the issue... Frankly i don't think it matters now .. leak is gone ....cheers

Answer (score 0):

ok Now am not getting any leaks from openAL .. What i have done is :-

- While initializing sources again  delete them first with their respective buffers and free any pcmData pointer.
- regenerate sources and buffers.
- Dont ever Delete openALContext and openALDevice . get context and device only once when your app starts . Delete them on Dealloc().

Hope this solves your openAl leak issues.

Cheers